# QtSPIM: Explanation for code shown without loading program

Tags: assembly, mips, qtspim, spim

The QtSPIM MIPS assembler already shows some lines of code even though there is no program loaded, like can be seen on https://ecs-network.serv.pacific.edu/ecpe-170/tutorials/qtspim-tutorial.

I assume this is required for loading programs, but I would be very interested in an exact explanation to understand all details.

Comment: The code is already commented so you can see what it does. The userspace text segment code is just there to set up a few registers and then call your `main` function. The kernel text segment code is the default exception handler.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment, which also partially answers my question. Neither being an expert for assembler nor for C programming, the comments next to the code are also cryptic to me. Therefore, a reference to a explanation what the code does would still be helpful for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A QtSPIM program consists of two parts: an exception handler, and a user program.

The default exception handler includes both a short user-mode startup code sequence (loaded at `0x00400000` as well as the actual exception handler located in kernel memory `.ktext`, which starts at `0x80000180`,

When you load your user program, it is appended to the user-mode code (from the exception handler) at about location `0x00400024`.  You can also see that until you load your program with your `main`, that the address of `main` (in that startup code) is taken as 0, aka undefined.

You can replace the default exception handler with your own.  Use `Simulator` menu, `Settings` submenu, `MIPS` tab, `Load Exception Handler` (or `Use default exception handler`).

In your exception handler file, you would put your actual handler after a `.ktext` directive, and, you would put your start sequence after a `.text` directive — which is optional. If you don't supply one then `main` has nowhere to return to, so to terminate the simulator normally, you would have to exit via `syscall` instead of simply returning.

The other popular simulator, MARS, does not include this default user mode startup code sequence so MARS programs always have to exit from `main` using a syscall.

The default exception handler prints the reason for the exception and doesn't do much else.

If you want to do interrupt driven console I/O, you would write your own exception handler, for example.  QtSPIM also supports a timer, which also uses the interrupt mechanism.  You can also implement trap handler (`teq`, `tne`, `teqi`, `tnei` instructions), but the `syscall` instruction is always handled by QtSPIM outside of the MIPS exception handling mechanism.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This information was exactly what I was looking for.