# QtSPIM MIPS Simulator: Register a1 and a2 get automatically changed

Tags: assembly, mips, spim

The QtSPIM MIPS simulator automatically sets the registers a1 and a2 to the following values upon execution of the first line of any assembler program:

```
R5  [a1] = 7ffff57c
R6  [a2] = 7ffff584
```

What is the reason for that? Is there a way to avoid it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QtSPIM loads a short start sequence that invokes `main`.  This start sequence sets `argc`, and `argv`, so that `main` can have a normal C-style signature: `int main(int argc, char*argv[]);`.

When you run QtSPIM, it first loads the kernel-mode exception handler file, which actually includes this user-mode startup sequence.  You should notice that your assembler program is loaded at `004000020` or so, and the code starting at `00400000` up to `00400018` is that user-mode startup.

See also this answer on [QtSPIM: Explanation for code shown without loading program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59823995/qtspim-explanation-for-code-shown-without-loading-program/59826061#59826061) which speaks to the exception handler file.

---

The way to avoid this is to load/specify your own exception handler file (see above link) that is empty — or at least doesn't have a `.text` section (only `.ktext`)   You will forgo the exception handler itself, but that doesn't do much except print the exception.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Having used a custom (empty) exception handler, I would have expected to registers a1 and a2 to be empty, because my code is not touching them. In case of the standard exception handler, I would completely understand that something gets written to the registers.

Comment: You can use the exception handler file feature to clear the these register yourself...

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I was looking for.